# Code-Igniter: load & send email in a library

Tags: codeigniter

I have a library in CodeIgniter called "someclass".

```
class someclass extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->database();

       // $this->load-> library('database');

    }
    function email($naar=0,$onderwerp=0,$bericht=0){
        if ($naar > 0 && $naar<10) {

            $to = "tester@test.com"
            //this is the part where it goes wrong            

            $CI =& get_instance();
            $this->load->library('email');               
            //some one said that i needed ti assign the library's
            $this->_assign_libraries();

            $this->email->from('tester@test.com', 'test');
            $this->email->to($to);
            $this->email->subject($onderwerp);
            $this->email->message("Test

                bericht :
                ".$bericht);

            $this->email->send();
            // echo $this->email-> print_debugger();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: someclass::$email

Filename: libraries/someclass.php

Line Number: 139
```

Comment: any reason you are doing this `$CI =& get_instance();`.  You aren't using it

Comment: yes becouse i tryed like a billion things and my code got messy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have 2 situations in my vision.

1. First you can **use a helper**. Create a .php file (ex: general_helper.php) which can be autoloaded or loaded where you will use it. Autoload if from config/autoload.php with 'general' name.

Here, you can create a method called sendEmail

```
function sendEmail($naar=0,$onderwerp=0,$bericht=0)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

        $CI->load->library('email');               
        //or autoload it from /application/config/autoload.php

        $CI->email->from('tester@test.com', 'test');
        $CI->email->to($to);
        $CI->email->subject($onderwerp);
        $CI->email->message("Test

            bericht :
            ".$bericht);

        $CI->email->send();

}
```

Load your custom library in your controller and call id with `sendEmail(....)`

1. You can **extend native email library class** and **create a method inside that class called sendEmail** for example:

   class MY_Email extends CI_Email {
       public function _*construct()
       {
       parent::*_construct();
       }
       public function sendEmail () ..... etc.
   }

From your controller load native library class, use `$this->load->library('email')` and send your email by calling `$this->email->sendEmail(...)`

Comment: Thanks. it is quite i time ago i asked this question and i already forgot about it. An helper is indeed what i needed. i was such a noob trying this in an library.  anyway. you have the correct awnser so you deserve credits. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it all wrong! Are you trying to write your own library? Or are you trying to write a controller for a page?

If you're trying to write a controller, you don't need to run the `get_instance()` function. Simply extends the `CI_Controller` class, load the appropriate library, in this case it's `email`, and use it according to the documentation. Also, controllers are to be put inside the `controllers` folder.

But if you're trying to write a library, you can't extend from the `CI_Controller` class. You'll also need to grab the instance of CodeIgniter using the `get_instance()` function and store it in a variable. After that simply use the object to load the `email` library and send the emails.

Also, I don't think you can call a method with an underscore prefix from that class. I'm talking about `$this->_assign_libraries()`. In CodeIgniter, a method prefixed with an underscore is a `private` function. Thus, you can't access it from within your own class. (Unless of course, it's a `protected` function and you extend the class).

Comment: oke thanks for the info:  First i want to make a library not a controller
i will try  the get_instance() function

Comment: i tryed:
   $myInstance =get_instance();
               $myInstance->load->library('email');               
                $myInstance->email->from('test@gmail.com', 'test');
                $myInstance->email->to($to);

withoud any luck. but i am guesing that i understand a library wrong. i thing i should make this a method in a controller.

it is an function to send emails, and i want to call it from multiple controllers

Comment: If you want to use the code from multiple controllers, yes you'll need to create a library. But if it's not working for some reason, you're probably still doing it wrong.

Comment: oke thenk you very much for the info...   i will do my homework better on code igniter libraries and i will try to figuere out what i am doing wrong.

again thanks for the help Kemal Fadillah